# What steps are needed to commit and push to GitHub from CodeBuild?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-codebuild

I’m trying to have `yarn` publish an NPM package in CodeBuild, and then push the updated `package.json` back to GitHub Enterprise. Everything is working except the push part. It’s not a credentials issue because the CodeBuild is able to fetch everything from the GitHub server (SSH has already been setup).

Once it has the pushed tag, it is:

1. Setting `user.name` and `user.email` for git config
2. Finding the branch that the tag was pushed to: `git branch —-contains tags/<tag> | sed -n 2p | awk ‘{printf $1}’`
3. Checking out that branch: `git checkout <branch>`
4. Publishing via `yarn publish —-no-git-tag-version —-new-version <version from tag>` which also changes and commits the `package.json` change.
5. Finally it runs `git push origin <branch>`

Step 1-4 seem to be working great, but step 5 just outputs “everything up-to-date” even though `yarn publish` changed and committed  the `package.json`.

What else needs to be done to commit/push from CodeBuild? I’ve also tried putting `git fetch —-unshallow` before everything in case it needed more info, but that didn’t change anything. It’s as if checking out a branch in CodeBuild doesn’t track the remote branch?

Comment: Use some investigative commands before and after 'yarn publish' to confirm your assumption that yarn has changed files, commands like "cat package.json" or "git status"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After step 4, it seems you haven't committed anything to your current branch.
Check `git status` for untracked and modified files, you can add these using `git add <files>` or add all using `git add .`.

Once this is done, you can use `git status` again to check that the files have been added correctly, and commit the files with `git commit` and you should be able to push successfully.

Comment: Haha, you're absolutely right! Adding `git status` after publishing showed the uncommitted `package.json`. What a silly mistake. When I ran `yarn publish` locally it _did_ commit `package.json` automatically so I'm not sure why that behavior is different in CodeBuild (maybe because of the `--no-git-tag-version` flag), but thanks a lot!